# Analyzing function $\;y=\large\frac{(x-a)^2(x+a)^2}{(x-a)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Which of these statements about this function is true?

$$y=\frac{(x-a)^2(x+a)^2}{(x-a)}$$

1. There is a hole at $x=a$.
2. There is a repeated zero at $x=-a$.
3. The function "behaves" like $y = x^4$ (is even, etc...)

I know the first statement is true, are the others true too? thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to state "there is a hole" and "there is a repeated zero"? I still don't understand what 3. is supposed to mean.

Comment: correct. and I think 3 means that since y=x^4 is even, then the function is also even. I'm not sure if they funtion is even or odd though. I think it is odd though

Comment: What does "end behaviour" mean?

Comment: whether the function is odd or even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

- Simplify (canceling terms), presuming $x \neq a$ (where the function is undefined - i.e., "where there is a hole"). *For help with simplifying, scroll over the "grey" box below.*

> $$\displaystyle y=\frac{{(x-a)^2}(x+a)^2}{{(x-a)}} = (x-a)(x+a)^2,\quad x\neq a$$

- What is the value of $\,y\,$ when $\,x = -a\,?\;$ How many factors of $\,(x + a)\,$ does the function have? So how many zeros at $x = -a$?
- Expand the factors (multiply the factors) to determine whether the *simplified function* is even or odd (is it anything "like $y = x^4$"?).

> $$\quad(x-1)(x+1)^2 \;=\; (x - 1)(x^2 + 2x + 1) \;=\;\;$$?

Also helpful when investigating a function like this (where $a$ is not necessarily known): let $a$ be some value, say $\,a = 1,\,$ and $\,a = -1.\;$ Then graph each of these functions; that may help you visualize what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So (if I did this right), I did get a hole at x=a. I got zeros at x=a and x=-a (twice), so is that considered a repeated zero? And, the highest power is x^3, which would mean that the graph is not like x^4, right?

Comment: Everything correct, except "zero at x = a". As you note, there is a "hole" at $x = a$: where the function is undefined. So $x = a$ cannot be a "zero". But there are repeated zeros at $x = -a$, and correct, the function is not like $y = x^4$!

Comment: +1 it is so funny to me that the notation gets hide. ;-)